# Screen is going upward when i call becomeFirstResponder in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

[BecomeFirstResponder pushing screen upward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWxhZ.png)

The name of first textField is txtCodeOne and when i call

```
txtCodeOne.becomeFirstResponder()
```

in viewDidLoad() it push the screen upward as shown in image.

After filling text in txtCodeOne when cursor moves to next field, screen become back to normal and don't goes upward even i call txtCodeOne.becomeFirstResponder().

Any ideas, how can i fix that?

Comment: try calling this method in `viewDidApper` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, helped me a few time ago

Comment: Yes, it working.

Comment: added some notice as answer, check it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling this method in `viewDidApper()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Notice if you are going to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` you should do it this way, because it can be called multiple times

```
private var didLayout = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !self.didLayout {
        self.didLayout = true
        self.txtCodeOne.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```